# How to SUM minus INT Currency

Tags: mysql, integer

I have a transaction table with positive and negative numbers and a budget table. A negative number will increase if being minus with budget.

bud_tab

| id | budget |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 90 |
| 2 | 80 |
| 3 | 50 |
| 4 | 30 |

trans_tab

| id | trans |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | -50 |
| 2 | 80 |
| 3 | -70 |
| 4 | 60 |

What query should I use to get an output like this:

| budget | trans | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 90 | -50 | 140 |
| 80 | 80 | 0 |
| 50 | -70 | 120 |
| 30 | 60 | -30 |

Comment: #1. Does `id` in source tables is primary/unique key? or there are duplicates? #2. Does the values list in `id` columns of source tables is identical? or it is possible that one value is present in one table but is absent in another? in last case - does some third table with all possible `id` values exists?

Answer (score 0):

From the look of output, this seems like a basic math calculations. Am I missing something ?

```
select budget, trans, budget - trans as total from bud_tab natural join trans_tab ;
```

Comment: I'll try with natural tab but why the ouput have only the label of the rows but no value..

Comment: Then I suppose the actual tables have more columns than what you provided  . This means `natural join` will try to join tables using all identical column names, which is like `ON bud_tab.id = trans_tab.id AND bud_tab.title=trans_tab.title` . If it's the case, use explict JOIN instead: `select budget, trans, budget - trans as total from bud_tab join trans_tab using(id) ;`